# NodeJS/Express, Receiving pdf in response body

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I have a node instance using express. It makes call to a JAVA backend. When I receive the response I check if there is a content-disposition header and react accordingly with the type of file.

The content of the response.body is the pdf in binary content. With content-type header "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8". I also receive a Content-Transfer-Encoding header set to binary.

If I call my JAVA backend directly from a REST client, everything is fine and I can view the raw body or download the file.

If I go with node, the PDF is blank. But has the correct number of pages.

Here's how I forward the respond to the frontend.

```
res.status(response.statusCode).set('content-disposition', response.contentDisposition).set('Content-Type', response.contentType).send(response.body);
```

Is it possible Express is converting it to some default encoding before I can even have access to the response ?

All I want to do is take the body response from my java backend ajust the headers and send it back to the frontend.

Thank you

**EDIT**
This is the options I pass to my request function

```
 method=GET, user=username, pass=password, uri=http://appsjava-veo01.hostname:8081/VEO/r/pap/pap5001/produire/311, Content-Type=*/*, Accept=*/*
```

Calling my http handler, and in the callback sending back the response

```
httpRequest(options, req, res, function(err, response){
        if (err){
            return next(err);
        }else{
            if (response.jsonResponse){
                res.status(response.statusCode).set('Content-Type', 'application/json').send(response.jsonResponse);
            }else{
                if (response.contentDisposition){
                    res.status(response.statusCode).set('Content-Disposition', response.contentDisposition).set('Content-Type', response.contentType).send(response.messageHtml);
                }else {
                    res.status(response.statusCode).set('Content-Type', 'application/json').send(JSON.stringify({
                        success: response.success,
                        message: response.message,
                        messageHtml: response.messageHtml,
                        dateJour: response.dateJour,
                        usager: response.usager
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    });


var httpRequest = function(options, req, res, callback) {
    var errorMsg, dateJour;
ASQ(function (done) {
        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (!response) {
                done.fail(error);
            } else {
                done(response);
            }
        });
    })
    .then(function (done, response) {
        var bodyResponse,
            httpResponse,
            jsonResponse,
            contentDisposition = response.headers['content-disposition'],
            usager = (req.session.cas) ? req.session.cas.user : 'nocas';
        dateJour = new Date().toJSON();

        //Validation et aiguillage selon les status code http
        if (response.statusCode === 401) {
            req.session.pt = '';
            httpResponse = {
                'statusCode': 401,
                'success': false,
                'message': '401 - Authorization requise',
                'messageHtml': response.body,
                'dateJour': dateJour,
                'jsonResponse': null,
                'usager': usager
            };
            return callback(null, httpResponse);

        } else if (response.statusCode.toString().charAt(0) === '2' || response.statusCode === 406 || response.statusCode === 428) {
                if (contentDisposition) {
                    var contentType = utils.extractContentType(contentDisposition);
                    httpResponse = {
                        'statusCode': response.statusCode,
                        'success': true,
                        'message': 'Téléchargement du fichier',
                        'messageHtml': response.body,
                        'dateJour': dateJour,
                        'jsonResponse': null,
                        'contentDisposition': contentDisposition,
                        'contentType': contentType,
                        'usager': usager
                    };
                    return callback(null, httpResponse);
                ...................
```

Comment: On a general note, application/pdf is a binary content type, it should not have any charset information attached to it.

Comment: Can you post the code that's making the call to the Java backend?

Comment: SOLVED !  Request assumes that the response is text, so it tries to convert the response body into a sring (regardless of the MIME type). This will corrupt binary data. If you want to get the raw bytes, specify a null encoding.